# Which version of SQL Server should I add to my setup file?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, installshield

I'm creating a WPF application in Visual Studio 2015. This application uses a local database that created a Microsoft SQL Server database file (`SqlClient`). I want to create a setup file with InstallShield but I don't know which version of SQL Server I should add to the redistributables.There is many version of SQL Server in redistributables page.
[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M5vk.png)

Comment: You might consider using a database more suitable to embedding. No version of SQL Server is trivial to install as part of an application setup. Have you ever seen [SQLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite/)?

Comment: I used SQLite before in android projects but I don't want to use SQLite in this project . I just wanna know which version of SQL Server is required for install my project.

Comment: Any version that supports the T-SQL code you are using and is compatible with the library you are using to access it. Safe bet would be the latest Express version but I wouldn't install an application that forced me to run a database server on my machine.

Comment: so what should I do if I don't add SQL Server to my project??

Comment: I would use SQLite. SQL Compact is also an option, you probably wouldn't have to change your code at all. A database server is meant to serve multiple clients, not just one application on one machine. I'm not saying it's not possible but it is way overkill and putting a burden on the user.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments, you could use SQLite or SQL Compact. The only downside of SQLite is that Entity Framework doesn't support EF migrations using it (you can use it with [3rd party plugins](https://github.com/bubibubi/db2ef6migrations) but it has some limitations).

To achieve what you want and still make use of Entity Framework support, I'd suggest [SQL Server Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express). You can distribute it along side your application and can embed it inside your installer.

Check [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/user_ed/2012/12/09/how-to-embed-sql-server-express-in-an-application/) post on MSDN on how to achieve that, it's old but helped me to understand what I've had to do on my end some time ago.